# Efficiency of Cloudinary, Imgix

Tags: cloudinary, imgix

I want to build My blog with attracting images like Travellers and  image manipulations like amazon, ebay, flipkart,etc. I have been suggested to use services like Cloudinary, Imgix, etc to resize/Edit my images since it would be better to store one version of each image although I'd need several versions with different sizes. But I would like to know whether these services are much efficient. Are there any issues?

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely an advantage to only loading images the size that you need them. The biggest bonus is going to be load times. We all know that users don't like to wait for pages to load. So if you have multiple copies or compress all of your images based on screen size, you will offer a better user experience. Google also bases search display on load times, which image size plays into. 
I also suggest using a service that offers CDN for images so that you can take advantage of caching.

Comment: I do work for Filestack and I strongly recommend trying out our service. You can get a free account at filestack.com